# In Ubuntu, how do I change the home path of Jenkins using the CLI?

Tags: jenkins, configuration, ubuntu

In the Jenkins web interface, under *Home directory* (Dashboard -> Mange Jenkins -> Configure System), the help section says the following:

- "By default, Jenkins stores all of its data in this directory on the
  file system", referring to /var/lib/jenkins
- "Edit the JENKINS_HOME variable in your Jenkins configuration file (e.g. /etc/sysconfig/jenkins on Red Hat Linux)"

However, my etc directory doesn't have a directory called sysconfig.

Running the following command returns a lot of files among which only the following seems relevant:

```
find ~/ -type f -name "config.xml"
<...>
/var/lib/jenkins/config.xml
<...>
```

The file contains the following field:

```
<workspaceDir>${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}</workspaceDir>
```

Is this the correct field to edit? If so, which syntax should I follow while entering the desired path?

Answer (score 1):

This question was already [asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192322/how-to-change-home-directory-of-jenkins) on Stack Overflow.  I'll copy the top answer here, but there are several other answers over there that you may find useful:

> For me on Jenkins 2.7.2 on RHEL 7.2 after already starting jenkins and
> configuring a build, I needed to:
>
> 1. Change the jenkins user's home directory
>
>    ```
>    sudo su -
>    service jenkins stop
>    vi /etc/passwd
>    #  change the /var/lib/jenkins to /home/jenkins or whatever
>    ```
> 2. Change the setting in the start script to also find it
>
>    ```
>    vi /etc/sysconfig/jenkins
>    #   change the JENKINS_HOME to /home/jenkins or what ever
>    ```
> 3. Copy all the data to the new location (eg: /home/jenkins)
>
>    ```
>    cd /home
>    cp -Rf /var/lib/jenkins .
>    chown -R jenkins:jenkins *
>    ```
> 4. Start it back up
>
>    ```
>    service jenkins start
>    ```
>
> And that seems to have done it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem on a Centos 7.9 system using Jenkins 2.346.2

Sometime around 2.332.1 Jenkins migrated from init.d to system.d, so the previous method of updating the /etc/sysconfig/jenkins (or /etc/default/jenkins) became deprecated.

You now use overrides through:  systemctl edit jenkins

Jenkins systemd reference:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/systemd-services/

Answer (score 0):

The following script can be used to do what you want:

```bash
# become root
sudo -i

# stop the jenkins service
systemctl stop jenkins

# create the directory where you want jenkins
mkdir -p /[path to your jenkins instance]

vi /etc/sysconfig/jenkins
# change JENKINS_HOME to /[path to your jenkins instance]

vi /etc/passwd
#  change the default /var/lib/jenkins to /[path to your jenkins instance]

mv -R /var/lib/jenkins /[path to your jenkins instance]

# grant ownership of all the files to jenkins
chown -R jenkins:jenkins .[path to your jenkins instance]

# start jenkins
systemctl start jenkins 

# if you want jenkins to start upon every reboot
systemctl enable jenkins
```